# Why class binding do not work with ngOnChanges?

Tags: angular

I am new at angular. I have tried to add a class if a property named `isMajor` is true. An if statement toggle the isMajor property depending on the value of `propName` generated by `ngOnChanges`.

If I remove this line

```
propName === 'major' ? this.isMajor = true : this.isMajor = false;
```

there is no problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-class-toggle-ngonchanges

```
/* tslint:disable:forin */
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-child',
  template: `
    <h3>Version {{major}}.{{minor}}</h3>
    <h4>Change log:</h4>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let change of changeLog" [class.major]="isMajor">{{change}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class HeroChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() major: number;
  @Input() minor: number;
  changeLog: string[] = [];
  isMajor = false;

  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    for (let propName in changes) {
      let changedProp = changes[propName];
      let to = JSON.stringify(changedProp.currentValue);
      propName === 'major' ? this.isMajor = true : this.isMajor = false;
      if (changedProp.currentValue == 0) return;
      if (changedProp.isFirstChange()) {
        this.changeLog.push(`Initial value of ${propName} set to ${to}`);
      } else {
        let from = JSON.stringify(changedProp.previousValue);
        this.changeLog.push(`${propName} changed from ${from} to ${to}`);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why this code does not add a 'major' class in each li that correspond to a major release ?

Why this does not work with ngOnChanges ?

Thank you =)

Comment: mate tbh i dont see any declared css with .major class. When I edited your stackblitz, I declared major css class and used nglass to Bind the Value. Works fine so far but there is another problem with ur logic

Answer (score 1):

Has nothing to do with angular, just basic JavaScript:

```
 this.isMajor = propName === ‘major’;
```

But besides that, your isMajor property belongs to the component, not the items in the list so you can’t have more than one value on it. You need a structure more like

```
changeLog: {change: string, isMajor: boolean}[]
```

And then assign it to the isMajor in the array and in your ngFor access the item properties

```
[class.major]=“change.isMajor”
```

Comment: His expression is valid Javascript and not the issue

Comment: it’s actually not valid but ok. Ternary operator is an assignment operator

Comment: Thank you. Even if I change that, this does not work. To make the class binding work, I have to remove the if statement from ngOnChanges.

Comment: You have more issues. Your isMajor property is on your component, not the items in your list

Comment: @bryan60 It isn't. It's a shorthand for an if/else statement if you are not using it in combination to an actual assignment operator.

Comment: JavaScript lets you get away with a lot of things you still shouldn’t do. Ternary should always be used as assignment and not as a short hand for if else

Comment: Thank both of you. I have to learn more basics. At least now I know that ngOnChanges is not the problem here. =)

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the `major` prop, but at the same time you are also updating the `minor` prop.

So when you are updating the `major` props, you have 2 changes. The first one set `isMajor` to true, and then right after it sets it back to `false`.

You can achieve the desired result by removing the `isMajor` update statement from the loop and using

```
this.isMajor = 'major' in changes;
```

outside of the loop instead.

Comment: Thank You. If I do that, I can't distinguish between major and minor. When I click on 'New major version' all the li obtain a 'major' class.

Comment: That would require a bigger refactoring of your entire code and logic, so it's a bit difficult to do here. You would need to manage your array of version inside the parent component as an array of objects instead of a array of string. Each object holding the version number, as well as a boolean indicating if it's a major version or a minor one.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a *direct* answer, but using `ngOnChanges` can be a pain - I generally try to avoid that if I can

It would be much simpler to create another child component e.g. `VersionListItemComponent`, which accepts as it's input the major/minor version, and has the `<li>` in it's template. Do the `ngFor` on this component, and then each of them will have a single major/minor value, and you can avoid the `ngOnChanges`. Just put the class check logic in the `ngAfterViewInit` of `VersionListItemComponent`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I asked it to learn. It is not a problem I have to resolve. But I feel better knowing that I am not the only one who think _using ngOnChanges can be a pain_